# Random large download across the office of Windows 10 desktops

Tags: windows, networking

Couple months ago, I've just completed the office-wide upgrade to Windows 10. We have about 40 Dell' desktops running Win 10 and MS Office, and no other business applications installed besides Malwarebytes, CCleaner, Chrome, Belarc.

Yesterday (Sept 20), users started complaining about their browsers failing to load websites. I've checked my LinkBalancer and noticed that random workstations downloading heavy amount of data while maxing out our two ISP: 100Mbps and 20Mbps. As they block the entire bandwidth, other users get times-out and not being able to get anything.

Unfortunately, we don't have proper network edge equipment where I can limit per session bandwidth.

This morning there are still couple of instances of massive downloads.

Any clue/idea I should check.

Thank you

Comment: Check what's causing the traffic

Comment: Run Resource Monitor or Performance Monitor on those workstations to determine which process is causing the high network consumption.

Comment: Here is one of the event caught on tape [link](https://imagebin.ca/v/2vrcHpmkN8v4)

Comment: [link](https://imagebin.ca/v/2vrf1gH8n4lI)

Comment: I was able to capture IPs that one of the impacted clients connect to, and almost half of them points to MS. So I went and found the latest Windows 10 update : "... 
September 20, 2016 — KB3193494 (OS Builds 14393.187 and 14393.189) 
We encountered a network transmission issue with update KB3189866 published on September 13, 2016, and the quickest way to address this issue was to reissue the update to all Content Delivery Networks. This new update KB3193494 has the same set of fixes as KB3189866. We apologize for any inconvenience this may have caused. "

Comment: Windows updates for new OS'es are larger in size than they were for older OS'es. If you don't have a local WSUS server you may want to consider setting one up and configuring the clients to use it. Having a local WSUS server means updates only need to traverse you internet WAN connection once. Then each client get the updates over your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few place you could check:

If you have some workstations having this massive download constantly:

1. Just to be sure, check for any irregular user activity: Torrent,
   movie files (avi,mkv) or steam.
2. Install wireshark on them. Wait for the massive download and sniff
   the packets and check for the IPs where the number of packets is the
   highest. Using the command `nslookup` with the IP may give you the
   name of the source, or just googling the IP.

If this is very random, there's 2 things you could check:

1. Go to a workstation where the massive download occurred and check if there weren't any recent update from windows (go to `Windows Update > Advanced Options > Update history`). If this is an update issue, check WSUS (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx).
2. [more difficult and time demanding] Find a way to monitor network activity: A feature on yours appliance or set up a server and put it between your workstations and your router.

Comment: I don't think it is any of the social sharing, torrents, etc. It is very random computers that pick up one after another to consume our bandwidth. Here are the IPs that one of the hyper computers connected [link](https://ibin.co/2vrofZvLaB3V.png).. Most of the connection have a single IP belonging to MS

Comment: I was planning to install Sophos UTM or similar as a security GW, but... didn't sell it well enough to the management. Life would be easier to deal with such incidents.

Comment: Check for the update history on the workstation. As you said before, there's KB3193494 and the x64 packet is 431MB (which can be a lot for 200 workstations). If this is the issue, the are 2 bad but fast solutions: disable automatic update through GPO or block the IP on your firewall. Good solutions: WSUS.

Comment: I know how you feel about managers blocking solutions. A low budget solutions would be installing a open source solutions on a server with 2 good nics, not easy but cheap :)

Comment: The funny part is... I am running Sophos UTM (installed on $300 supermicro server) at my home network, and at our multi-$Mil business it is not a priority.

Comment: I know that feeling. People only want to put money on IT when something fails or it is extremely necessary for their projects, otherwise, they only see us as expenses and won't expend a single penny :(